# ArgumentOutOfRange Exception when assigning datasource of datagridview in mono

Tags: exception, datagridview, mono

ArgumentOutOfRange Exception when assigning datasource in datagridview.

Edit :
This code is works fine when i use List in place of BindingList.

Environment : 
Mono 4.0.12. C# winform application

Code :

```
public class DataGridViewStudyReference : CustomControls.DataGridViewDataEntry<StudyRefrenceValueBusinessObjectNew>
{ 
}

public class DataGridViewDataEntry<BindingSourceType> : DataGridView
{
        public void ResetDataSource()
        {
            if (DataEntrySource == null)
            {
                DataEntrySource = new BindingList<BindingSourceType>();
                this.DataSource = DataEntrySource;
            }
            else
            {
                DataEntrySource.Clear();
            }
        }
}

public class StudyRefrenceValueBusinessObjectNew
{
    public long StudyReferenceID { get; set; }

    public long StudyID { get; set; }

    public int GenderValue { get; set; }

    public int AgeInitial { get; set; }

    public int AgeFinal { get; set; }

    public string TextValue { get; set; }

    public int ValueInitial { get; set; }

    public int ValueFinal { get; set; }

}
```

full exception detail is as follows

Message :

> Index is less than 0 or more than or equal to the list count.
>   Parameter name: index 1

Stack Trace :

```
  at System.Collections.ArrayList.ThrowNewArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.String name, System.Object actual, System.String message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item (Int32 index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCollection.get_Item (Int32 index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCollection:get_Item (int)
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CalculateColumnCellWidth (Int32 index, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode mode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.AutoResizeColumnInternal (Int32 columnIndex, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode mode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.AutoResizeColumnsInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnColumnAddedInternal (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnColumnCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.CollectionChangeEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.OnCollectionChanged (System.ComponentModel.CollectionChangeEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.Add (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DoBinding () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ReBind () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_DataSource (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LabManagement.WinForm.CustomControls.DataGridViewDataEntry`1[LabManagement.Model.Study.StudyRefrenceValueBusinessObjectNew].ResetDataSource () [0x00020] in /home/alit/Projects/LabManagementSolution/LabManagement/LabManagement.WinForm/CustomControls/DataGridViewDataEntry.cs:64
```

Can anybody help me, why this exception occurring ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the cause of problem.

In my DataGridView `AutoSizeColumnsMode` mode was set to `AllCell` i changed it to `None`. Then this error removed.
It seems there is something internal problem in column size calculation in mono framework, i think this a bug of mono framework. However currently my issue is resolved.